# Spring @Scheduled does not work appropriate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, scheduled-tasks

I have a method that should run at some delay, make request to api and add the new photo to database. So, `addPhoto` is working fine. It can print some info, make a request, but doesn't add the photo. I checked the database and there are only one photo, that i added manually.

```
@Component("restBean")
@Service
public class RestService {
    private static final String url1 = "https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1324&camera=fhaz&api_key=DEMO_KEY";

    private PhotoDao photoDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setPhotoDao(PhotoDao photoDao) {
        this.photoDao = photoDao;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void addPhoto() {
        System.out.println("TIME HAS COME");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate
                .getForEntity(url1,
                        Response.class);
        Photo[] photos = response.getBody().getPhotos();
        this.photoDao.save(photos[0]);
    }
}
```

I have tested this method and all works except the last string. I checked that i get the response and can get the object from it.

```
this.photoDao.save(photos[0]);
```

That's my DAO class

```
@Repository
public class PhotoDaoImpl implements PhotoDao {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PhotoDaoImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Photo photo) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(photo);
        logger.info("Photo successfully saved. Photo details: {}", photo);
    }

    @Override
    public Photo findOne(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Photo photo = (Photo) session.load(Photo.class, new Integer(id));
        logger.info("Photo successfully loaded. Photo details: {}", photo);

        return photo;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Photo> getAll() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

That's my spring xml configuration

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

<!-- This helps in mapping the logical view names to directly view files under a certain pre-configured directory -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- Database Information -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url"
              value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DayDatabase"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>net.yan.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- It register the beans in context and scan the annotations inside beans and activate them -->
<context:component-scan base-package="net.yan"/>
<!-- This allow for dispatching requests to Controllers -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<!-- PhotoDao and PhotoService beans -->
<bean id="photoDao" class="net.yan.dao.PhotoDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="photoService" class="net.yan.service.PhotoServiceImpl">
    <property name="photoDao" ref="photoDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="restService" class="net.yan.service.RestService">
    <property name="photoDao" ref="photoDao"/>
</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="restBean" method="addPhoto" fixed-delay="5000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduler id="myScheduler"/>
```

UPD: To be clear, i have another method, that make request and add to database. It's in the same class that doesn't work.

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
@Transactional
public void contextRefreshedEvent() {
    if (this.photoDao.checkDataBase()) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate
                .getForEntity(url,
                        Response.class);
        Photo[] photos = response.getBody().getPhotos();
        this.photoDao.save(photos[0]);
    }
}
```

UPD2: There's link to full project https://github.com/Kabowyad/Test-Project/tree/api-test/src/main/java/net/yan/service

Comment: try using session.saveOrUpdate(photo); in your save() method of dao instead of session.persist(photo);

Comment: @ParthBhuva. I changed to saveOrUpdate and nothing changed.

Comment: have you found any error in console?

Comment: @ParthBhuva No. http://imgur.com/a/4jRX5 As you can see img_src, sol - everything fine, but nothing added to database.

Comment: Your scheduled method isn't `@Transactional` also either `@Component` or `@Service` is enough you don't need both.